# influxdb: how to filter query by stddev

Tags: function, filter, max, influxdb

I tried to filter out incorrect peaks from my temperature measurements. For instance I have a mean of 15°C with little variation. But sometimes my sensor sends 0°C or 4°C, which is a sending error. I tried

`select temperature from "sensor" where temperature > mean(temperature) - stddev(temperature)`

this seems to work. However, the upper bound does not:

`select temperature from "sensor" where temperature < mean(temperature) + stddev(temperature)`

This simply reveals

> Success! (no results to display)

Even worse is that

`select temperature from "sensor" where temperature < max(temperature)`

also reveals

> Success! (no results to display)

which seems to be a bug to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: > this seems to work. 

It is not working. The query was not malformed and was properly received, so the Admin UI is reporting "Success" but the "No results to display" means that nothing matched your query results.

Functions are not valid outside of the SELECT clause. It seems like a bug in the Admin UI that it is not reporting a syntax error.

I would recommend using the [CLI](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.11/tools/shell/) for all queries, as the Admin UI obscures too many things.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is

`SELECT temperature FROM sensor WHERE temperature > 4`

To accomplish your original goal of using a STDDEV and MEAN to eliminate out of scope values, look into [Kapacitor](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor). It is the batch/stream processing companion to InfluxDB and supports arbitrary user defined functions, as well as maintaining state over time. There are no subfunctions or HAVING clause yet in InfluxDB, so it cannot do what you desire.